# Normalization and Denormalization

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, machine-learning-model, normalization, metric

I have few queries. 1) Is normalization required for ANN / CNN /LSTM ?  2) If we normalize the data with MinMax Scaler, then in that case how to denormalize it and when to denormalize it so that we can get the Error Metrics in the original format?